# Closure of a constant

Tags: definition, type-theory

Consider a type $T$, and a set $S$ containing elements of type $T$.

An object $f$ of type $T→T→T$ (or $T^2 → T$) is a function and it is closed under $S$ if any two elements of $S$ applied to $f$ returns an element of $S$.
The same goes if $f$ has type $T→T$.

But what if $f$ has type $T$ (i.e., it is a constant, and not a function)? Saying that this $f$ is closed under $S$ is the same as saying that $f$ is an element of $S$?

Comment: Things of type $T$ have a natural correspondence with things of type $()\to T$ where $()$ is the unit type. Applying the definition of closure for function types gives essentially the definition you suggested.

Comment: As a kind of side issue, types don't have elements. You could talk about *terms* of a type, but there is no guarantee that every value of (an interpretation of) a type can be expressed as a term. Alternatively, *if* you have an interpretation of your type theory that maps types to sets, then you could talk about the interpretation of a value of a function type as being or not being closed with respect to a subset. In type theories with subset types or, to a lesser extent, dependent sums, you could formulate an internal notion of being closed with respect some predicate on the type.